# How to load a local image on a gatsby source plugin?

Tags: gatsby

I have a json file and a folder with images

```
plugins/
└── gatsby-source-cars/
    ├── images/
    ├── cars.json
    └── gatsby-node.js
```

the file `cars.json` contains an array and each index is an object that contains a key with the relative path to the image

I want to load the image file on sourceNodes instead just the path to use with `gatsby-image` plugin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you want to process your local images with sharp since you said you want to use it with `gatsby-image`, this means you have `gatsby-plugin-sharp` and `gatsby-transformer-sharp` installed.

Usually `gatsby-source-filesystem` is necessary to load the image as File node. But `gatsby-transformer-sharp` only checks if a node has the field 'extension' and -- if it is one of the valid file types -- processes it. We can 'trick' it into thinking our node is a File node, by giving it the fields `extension` & `absolutePath`.

Given this structure:

```
plugins/
└── gatsby-source-my-plugin/
    ├── images/
    |     └──image01.png
    ├── images.json  //  [{ "01": "./images/image01.png" }]
    └── gatsby-node.js
```

`gatsby-node.js` could look like this:

```js
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs-extra')

exports.sourceNodes = async ({ actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest }) => {
  const { createNode } = actions

  const imageList = await fs.readJson(path.resolve(__dirname, './images.json'))
  imageList.forEach(img => {

    const [ id, imgPath ] = Object.entries(img)[0]
    const { name, ext } = path.parse(imgPath) // get file name & extension
    const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, imgPath)
    const data = {
      name,
      ext,
      absolutePath,                  // <-- required
      extension: ext.substring(1),   // <-- required, remove the dot in `ext`
    }
    const imageNode = {
      ...data,
      id: createNodeId(`my-plugin-image-${id}`),
      children: [],
      internal: {
        type: 'MyPluginNode',
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(data)
      }
    }

    createNode(imageNode)
  })
}
```

Later, you can query the images:

```
{
  allMyPluginNode {
    nodes {
      childImageSharp {
        fixed(width:200) {
          src
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Would you mind checking if I'm doing it right [gatsby-node.js](https://github.com/zsobral/pokedex-gatsby/blob/master/plugins/gatsby-source-pokedex/gatsby-node.js)?

Answer (score 5):

A way to go about transforming image file paths in json to images with `gatsby-image` without tapping directly into `gatsby-node.js` is to use the plugin [gatsby-transformer-json](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-json/).

When used in conjunction with `gatsby-source-filesystem`, this allows you to query your json objects.

So assuming you have followed the [setup](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/working-with-images/) for `gatsby-image`, if you have the following structure

```
src/
└── images/
    └──bar.png
└── content/
    └──foo.json
```

And `foo.json` contains **relative links** to the image locations such as

```
[
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "src": "../images/bar.png"
  }
]
```

Then you can query them like

```
query MyQuery {
  allFooJson {
    edges {
      node {
        name
        imgSrc {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxHeight: 64, maxWidth: 64) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that they [must be relative links](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/8312).

Comment: This answer deserves waaaaay more upvotes. Lifesaver thank you!!!