# Gatsby Node Api: creating a custom node, processing an image from json data

Tags: gatsby

I have a json file that describes my personal projects, one of the attributes is an image. I'd like to make the images in the data available as a `childImageSharp` query on a node I'm creating called `allProject` through `graphql`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55992433/how-to-load-a-local-image-on-a-gatsby-source-plugin/56012718#56012718) has an answer that seems like it should work, but for some reason it does not. I found that answer from [this blog post](https://freddydumont.com/blog/how-to-source-images-and-data-from-json-files-in-gatsby).

My `project.json` data file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "A Neat Title",
        "image": "static/images/some_image.jpeg",
        "alt": "Alt text",
        "description": "A neat description",
        "link": "https://867-5309.com"
    },
    ...
]
```

I have placed this code into my `gatsby-node.js` file. It creates a set of `allProject` nodes and a set of `allProjectImage` nodes. The `allProjectImage` nodes *should* result in nodes processed by `gatsby-transformer-sharp`, but aren't for some reason. The `allProject` node has an `allProjectImage` node as a property.

```
const { createFilePath } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem")
const path = require("path")

const projects = require('./src/data/projects.json')

/**
 * https://freddydumont.com/blog/how-to-source-images-and-data-from-json-files-in-gatsby
 * 
 * Create custom Project nodes.
 *
 * We need to 'trick' the sharp transformer to process the image file
 * by building a node with the structure of a File.
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56012718
 */
exports.sourceNodes = ({ actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest }) => {
  projects.forEach((card) => {
    const {
      title,
      description,
      link,
      image,
      alt,
    } = card;

    // name, extension and absolute path are required to build a File node
    const { name, ext } = path.parse(image);
    const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "./", image);

    // this data corresponds to a File node that Sharp can process
    const data = {
      name,
      ext,
      absolutePath, // <-- required
      extension: ext.substring(1), // <-- required, remove the dot in `ext`
    };

    // build and create the image node
    const imageNode = {
      ...data,
      id: createNodeId(`card-image-${name}`),
      children: [],
      internal: {
        type: 'ProjectImage',
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(data),
      },
    };
    actions.createNode(imageNode)

    const node = {
      title,
      description,
      link,
      // when imageNode is created, the sharp plugin adds childImageSharp to the node
      // so it will be available under the `image` field.
      image: imageNode,
      alt,
      id: createNodeId(`project-${title}`),
      internal: {
        type: 'Project',
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(card),
      },
    };

    actions.createNode(node);
  });
};
```

However, GraphiQL does not show that the images are being processed into a form that contains a `childImageSharp`. What I see is this:
[image: GraphiQL showing that there is no child image sharp]

The only thing that I can think is that the files might be processed twice. Once by `gatsby-transformer-sharp` in its own lifecycle, and again by the `sourceNodes` function, somehow preventing/removing the `childImageSharp` properties.

My project structure:

```
├── gatsby-browser.js
├── gatsby-config.js
├── gatsby-node.js
├── gatsby-ssr.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── _theme.scss
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── carousel.module.scss
│   │   ├── carousel.tsx
│   │   ├── footer.js
│   │   ├── footer.module.scss
│   │   ├── header.js
│   │   ├── header.module.scss
│   │   ├── layout.js
│   │   └── layout.module.scss
│   ├── data
│   │   └── projects.json
│   ├── global.scss
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── 404.js
│   │   ├── about.js
│   │   ├── about.module.css
│   │   ├── contact.js
│   │   ├── contact.module.scss
│   │   ├── index.module.scss
│   │   └── index.tsx
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── thought-page-layout.js
│   │   └── thought-page-layout.module.scss
│   └── utils
│       └── typography.js
├── static
│   └── images
│       ├── lifegraph.png
│       └── tmd.png
└── webpack.config.js
```

In my `gatsby-config.js` file, I have specified my `static/images` directory for the image source.

```
const path = require(`path`)

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Kyle Shores`,
    description: `To communicate clearly the science of climate, to pursue and describe the benefits of simple living, to allow a window into my personal life shall be the purpose of this site.`,
    author: `Kyle Shores`,
  },
  plugins: [
    ...
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: path.join(__dirname, `static`, `images`),
      },
    },
    `gatsby-remark-images`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
  ],
}
```

Other plugins that I use (but that I didn't show) are `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`, `gatsby-plugin-sass`, `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`, `gatsby-plugin-page-creator`, `gatsby-plugin-mdx`, `gatsby-remark-images`, `gatsby-plugin-manifest`, and `gatsby-plugin-typography`. My gatsby version is 2.30.3. Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: What about your `allImageSharp` node? Can you find your image there?

Comment: Yes, I can. @FerranBuireu

Comment: Is this line retrieving the correct path? `absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "./", image)` ?

Comment: @FerranBuireu, no it was not, but I changed it to `./static/images` and printed `absolutePath`. I have verified that the file location and `absolutelPath` are the same. It's like `gatsby-transformer-sharp` is not processing the node. I wonder if how nodes are processed by that plugin has changed since the original answer was written. I'll try to find out

Comment: Try something like: `const absolutePath = path.resolve(${__dirname}/static/images`;` I think you may need to add the images inside the `/src` folder anyway, but as a first approach try hardcoding the path.

Comment: So, it turns out this is a problem already solved by `gatsby-transformer-json`. https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/8312

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your images to another location inside the `/src` folder and use relative paths to point it:

```
├── gatsby-browser.js
├── gatsby-config.js
├── gatsby-node.js
├── gatsby-ssr.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── _theme.scss
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── carousel.module.scss
│   │   ├── carousel.tsx
│   │   ├── footer.js
│   │   ├── footer.module.scss
│   │   ├── header.js
│   │   ├── header.module.scss
│   │   ├── layout.js
│   │   └── layout.module.scss
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── images   <-- place your images here
│   │   │     └── some_image.jpeg  
│   │   └── projects.json
│   ├── global.scss
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── 404.js
│   │   ├── about.js
│   │   ├── about.module.css
│   │   ├── contact.js
│   │   ├── contact.module.scss
│   │   ├── index.module.scss
│   │   └── index.tsx
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── thought-page-layout.js
│   │   └── thought-page-layout.module.scss
│   └── utils
│       └── typography.js
├── static
│   └── images
│       ├── lifegraph.png
│       └── tmd.png
└── webpack.config.js
```

Then, change your JSON structure to point to the correct image path and change the `absolutePath` accordingly. In addition, I think you are not creating the node properly since you are missing some logic:

```
  const imageList = await fs.readJson(path.resolve(__dirname, './images.json'))
  imageList.forEach(img => {

    const [ id, imgPath ] = Object.entries(img)[0]
    const { name, ext } = path.parse(imgPath) // get file name & extension
    const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, imgPath)
    const data = {
      name,
      ext,
      absolutePath,                  // <-- required
      extension: ext.substring(1),   // <-- required, remove the dot in `ext`
    }
```

In [Derek's answer](https://freddydumont.com/blog/how-to-source-images-and-data-from-json-files-in-gatsby), he's looping through a provided JSON to get the image path to create the schema node, it's not mandatory but it's a way of telling where the images are. You are omitting that part (because you are trying to use it with one image right now) but the absolute path looks odd to me:

```
const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "./", image);
```

As a first approach, if you don't want to change the project's structure, try something like:

```
const absolutePath = path.resolve(${__dirname}/static/images`;
```

Comment: It looks like `gatsby-transformer-sharp` only creates nodes if the type is a `File`. That is a change added in October from last year. https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/commit/001e045c92dfd37a7d573d75ee9d81ae44c8e7a5#diff-16640b1b91df7d5e5b720e9aacc0458ecd82272cd271693a29d0c442bff1a318

Comment: Well, it's not the path. I verified that `absolutePath` is correct. Thank you for your suggestions though. And, if you click on the link, you'll see that this change is new. They now explicitly require setting a file type, but the type of my node is `ProjectImage`, so the plugin will skip it. Trying to set the type to `File` causes gatsby to throw an error because that is a type reserved by `gatsby-filesystem`.

Comment: Then, a possible solution is to downgrade the dependency version

Comment: Since in your `allImageSharp` there is your image, another thing you can do is to pass the path (or any other identifier) by context and query the image and get it in your template to make another query (filtered by that parameter)

Comment: if these images are coming from the json file, how would I pass them to the graphql query? Aren't all queries supposed to be static? As a side note, I'm investigating how `gatsby-plugin-mdx` adds images to its nodes, since this seems to essentially be the same thing. I'll report back if I figure it out how to make a composite node with what already exists using what I find there.

Comment: At the build-time, when you are creating pages in your `gatsby-node.js`, you can always pass from one node schema a unique parameter using context (let's say image name) and use that name to filter in `allImageSharp` images, using 2 queries in your template (one for the content and one for the image) you'll be able to have both.

Comment: Ah. Hmm. I was not planning on making a template for this. I wanted this to be inside of a component, not a page, so I wasn't planning on using the `createPages` API.

Answer (score 0):

Freddy dumont's solution works with these versions

```
"gatsby-plugin-sharp": "~2.7.1",
"gatsby-source-filesystem": "~2.4.1",
"gatsby-transformer-sharp": "~2.5.21",
```

There was an internal change (Oct 2020ish) requiring the file to be of type "File", which only gatsby-souce-fs can assign.

Another hack is to collect the node id's of the images

```
// gatsby-node.js
exports.onCreateNode = ({
  node,
  createNodeId,
  getNode,
  actions: { createNodeField },
}) => {
  if (node.internal.type === "ImageSharp") {
const {parent, id} = node
// this is the File nodeId and ImageSharp node id
}
```

You can use them to link the image node in onCreateNode, or in sourceNodes (which runs after onCreateNode).

Linking:

```
imageField___NODE: myImageNodeId,
```

thats _ _ _NODE for gatsby to add gql link.

You can then access it under `imageField`.

I'm sure there's a better way, but this works.