# iterating over data including image in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image

In Gatsby I would like to iterate over an array, which contains objects. One of the properties of each object would be an image. I would like to be able to use Gatsby Image.

Here is one example of when I'd like to do so: a page on a website with a gallery of images, each image opens a particular associated video when clicked. Perhaps I'd like 20, 50, or even 100+ objects in the array:

```
const videos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Festival 2018',
    url: 'https://www.youtube.com',
    img: // HOW TO ACHIEVE?
  },
  // Many more objects
]
```

```
videos.map((item) => {
  return (
    <Img
      key={item.id}
      fluid= // HOW TO ACHIEVE?
      alt={item.name}
      onClick={() => openPlayer(item.url)}
    />
  )
})
```

I understand how to query for single images with GraphQL; or how to query multiple images and use aliases; or how to query all images from a folder. But I have't worked out how to achieve my goal. There's probably a better way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use internal images in `gatsby-image` you need to allow Gatsby and their transformers and sharps to know where the images are located using the [`gatsby-source-filesystem`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem/). This will create queryable nodes from your images and will allow you to use `gatsby-image` with them.

Applied to your case, you need to put all images in the same folder, let's say `/src/images` and:

```
const path = require(`path`)

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: path.join(__dirname, `src`, `images`),
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
  ],
}
```

There, your JSON object will look like:

```
const videos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Festival 2018',
    url: 'https://www.youtube.com',
    img: '/relative/path/to/your/image.extension',
    extension: 'png'
  },
  // Many more objects
]
```

*Note: thanks [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13714522/john) for the clarification about the `extension` field. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56012718/13714522*

In your case, since you are using a JSON-based source, you will need to add the [`gatsby-transformer-plugin`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-json/). The configuration will look like:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-transformer-json`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `./src/data/`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

*Note: assuming that the JSON is placed in `/src/data`*

Also assuming that your JSON file is named `data.json`, if everything is properly set, Gatsby will create a GraphQL node called `allDataJson`. Then you only last to create a query (page query or static query) with the following content:

```
{
  allDataJson {
    edges {
      node {
        name
        url
        id
        img {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 1000, quality: 100) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Note: check your exact query in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground*

If your paths are correct, Gatsby will create the `childImageSharp` node which will allow you to use your own internal images within [`gatsby-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/) feature. Since your queried data is stored inside `props.data`, your final loop should look like:

```
props.data.allDataJson.edges.node.map((item) => {
  return (
    <Img
      key={item.id}
      fluid={item.img.childImageSharp.fluid}
      alt={item.name}
      onClick={() => openPlayer(item.url)}
    />
  )
})
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot. However I had to do one final step: the img field was only returning the string, not giving the childImageSharp node. In order for the path to become a childImageSharp node, I had to add another property to each object! `"extension": "png"` or `"extension": "jpg"` as appropriate. A slight inconvenience but seems to work. I got this final step from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56012718/13714522)

Comment: {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Example title",
    "url": "https://www.youtube.com",
    "img": "../images/video-img/trio.png",
    "extension": "png"
  },

Comment: Nice @John I'm glad it helped. Thanks for the insights, you're completely right. I will update the answer by adding your approach for those who may help :)

Comment: For anyone coming across this question & answer, `gatsby-image` has now been deprecated and you're encouraged to switch to `gatsby-plugin-image`. See https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/image-migration-guide