# Importing images to GraphQL via gatsby-node is not working: childImageSharp is missing

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm trying to load images from a JSON file into GraphQL using [Gatsby Node](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/) and the [Sharp transformer](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-sharp/) pipeline. The content nodes get created, but the `childImageSharp` and `gatsbyImageData` attributes are missing, which leads me to believe that there is something wrong with my setup.

I create a minimal example on Github to make the problem reproducible: https://github.com/stekhn/gatsby-image-sourcing

**Project structure**

```
src
├── data
│   └── projects.json
├── images
│   └── projects
│       ├── adam-vradenburg-sWAAhaoVuko-unsplash.jpg
│       ├── radek-homola-RfTD9NoLMEE-unsplash.jpg
│       ├── steven-kamenar-MMJx78V7xS8-unsplash.jpg
│       ├── will-tarpey-82pi_nJbE5M-unsplash.jpg
│       └── wolfgang-hasselmann-ZM4IxIcF9AU-unsplash.jpg
└── pages
    ├── 404.js
    └── index.js
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-image-sourcing",
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^3.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^1.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^3.3.1",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^3.3.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^3.3.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  }
}
```

**gatsby-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "Gatsby Image Sourcing",
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/projects/`,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

**gatsby-node.js:**

```
const path = require("path");
const projects = require("./src/data/projects.json");

// Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56012718
exports.sourceNodes = ({ actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest }) => {
  projects.forEach((project) => {
    const { title, year, tags, image } = project;
    const { name, ext } = path.parse(image);

    const absolutePath = path.resolve(
      __dirname,
      "src/images/projects",
      image
    );

    const imageData = {
      name,
      ext,
      absolutePath,
      extension: ext.substring(1),
    };

    console.log(imageData);
  
    const imageNode = {
      ...imageData,
      id: createNodeId(`project-card-image-${name}`),
      internal: {
        type: "projectCardsImage",
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(imageData),
      },
    };

    actions.createNode(imageNode);

    const node = {
      title,
      year,
      tags,
      image: imageNode,
      id: createNodeId(`project-card-${title}`),
      internal: {
        type: "projectCards",
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(project),
      },
    };

    actions.createNode(node);
  });
};
```

**projects.json**

```
[
  {
    "title": "Project 1",
    "year": "2021",
    "tags": ["foo", "bar"],
    "image": "adam-vradenburg-sWAAhaoVuko-unsplash.jpg"
  }
]
```

The image paths seem fine and gatsby-node.js is running without problems. Yet when I inspect the `projectCards` and `projectCardsImage` in the GraphiQL explorer, it seem like the Gatsby Transformer Sharp never ran. Normally, I would expect to see the attribute `childImageSharp` to be part of `image`.

[image]

I'm well aware that there are other way of loading and using images, which work fine. But right now, I'm kind of married to the idea of using Gatsby Node to populate the GraphQL database with exactly the kind of objects, I need in my components.

**References**

- [How to load a local image on a gatsby source plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55992433/how-to-load-a-local-image-on-a-gatsby-source-plugin/56012718#56012718)
- https://freddydumont.com/blog/how-to-source-images-and-data-from-json-files-in-gatsby

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the path for images should be:

```
"image": "../images/projects/adam-vradenburg-sWAAhaoVuko-unsplash.jpg"
```

With the current configuration Gatsby is generating an `id` based on the string, not on the GraphQL node you are generating in the `sourceNodes` function, which looks good to me.

Comment: I think this only true when using `gatsby-transformer-json` to source a JSON file and the corresponding images within. I tried all different paths to no avail. Probably the best idea to throw gatsby-node out of the window and go with the `gatsby-transformer-json` approach.

Comment: Haha, yes I think so. Keep me posted

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have the same problem, I followed the exact tutorials last year this was working in v2.  FYI I've opened an issue on gatsby https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/31380

Comment: The answer to the issue is here: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/31382#discussioncomment-727651